# Problem running Macros without opening the file

Tags: excel, vba, vbscript

I wanted to run macros using the command prompt, the macros are placed under a sheet in excel. I created a `VBScript` and let it automatically run in command prompts, but it shows "The macro may not be available in this workbook or all macros may be disabled."

**This is my VBA code**

[image]

**This is my VBS**

```
'Create Excel App Instance & Open Xlsm File
Set objExcelApp = CreateObject("Excel.Application")
objExcelApp.Visible = True
objExcelApp.DisplayAlerts = False

'Define Macro File & Path
sFilePathXlsm = "C:\Users\roeyj\OneDrive\Desktop\Intern\Monthly PM\Service Contracts as of 2022 (macro).xlsm"
Set iWb = objExcelApp.Workbooks.Open(sFilePathXlsm)

'1. Run 1st Macro in another Excel
sMacroToRun = "'" & sFilePathXlsm & "'!Sheet3.contract_vba"
objExcelApp.Run sMacroToRun


'Save & Close file
iWb.Save
iWb.Close
objExcelApp.DisplayAlerts = True
objExcelApp.Quit
```

**This is what the command prompt shows**

[image]

The excel file is opened but the macros don't run, I need help with this.

Comment: Are all macros disabled like the error message says?

Comment: @braX, i have enabled all the macros settings in excel. Shouldn't be the setting problems, i think there is something wrong in my VBScript

Comment: Please do not post your code as images. No one can copy/paste it then.

Comment: If you want a macro to be available to any workbook, then put it in the personal workbook.

Comment: @braX ohh so sorry,

Comment: @SolarMike I need the correct codes for me to run the macros in the Sheet using Command prompt

Comment: Try `objExcelApp.Run "'" & iWb.Name & "'!Sheet3.contract_vba"`

Comment: You still have images of code instead of text. Please edit your question to replace them with the actual text.

Answer (score 1):

`Run` doesn't want the full path, so try:

```
 objExcelApp.Run "'" & iWb.Name & "'!Sheet3.contract_vba"
```